# Calling a C++ macro with fewer arguments

Tags: c++, macros, g++, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to call function-like-macros with less that all the parameters in linux?
Actually doing this only generates a warning in Visual Studio (warning 4003) and unassigned variables replaces with "".

But compiling it using g++ generates an error in linux ("error: macro *** requires ** arguments, but only ** given").

Is there any possible way to disable this or overcome it?

Comment: If you are using C++ you should be using inline functions instead of macros.  In fact, in C++ you should avoid using the preprocessor as much as possible.

Comment: Yep... if you use them for anything but include guards you are a macrobator. ;-)

Comment: There's still a few situations in C++ where preprocessor directives and/or macros are the only answer, for example wrapping code that should be included in debug builds but not compiled in at all in release builds. But yes, generally they should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of arguments in a macro invocation must exactly match the number of parameters in the macro definition.  So, no, you cannot invoke a macro with fewer arguments than it has parameters.

To "overcome" it, you can define multiple differently named macros with different numbers of parameters.

C++0x (which is not yet standard, but which your compiler might partially support) adds support for variadic macros which can be called with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: GCC supports variadic macros since a long time. I don't know if they work the same as in C++0x though. He should give them a try

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html

Here it says that variadic macros come from C99. Shouldn't them be in C++ too ?

Comment: @asr:  Variadic macros were added to C in C99 (in 1999); the current C++ standard was approved in 1998 and does not have variadic macros.  They have been added to the forthcoming C++0x.  gcc might support them when compiling C++ code, but if it does it is as a language extension or as preemptive support for C++0x.

Answer (score 2):

The standard (§16.3 - Macro replacement) is clear that you have to pass the same number of arguments:

> "If the identiﬁer-list in the macro
>   deﬁnition does not end with an
>   ellipsis, the number of arguments
>   (including those arguments consisting
>   of no preprocessing tokens) in an
>   invocation of a function-like macro
>   shall equal the number of parameters
>   in the macro deﬁnition."

I don't know of any g++ option to override this.